# Show feature info when hover with OpenLayers 3.13.0

Tags: javascript, hover, gis, openlayers-3

I want to add to my map information on the vector layers when the users hovers over a feature. I want to replicate this example, but it looks like there are function that are no longer existing (ol.FeatureOverlay, but still exists in the API ?!)

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.0/examples/vector-layer.html

Anyone know how I can use it with the version 3.13 ?

Thanks

Comment: `ol.FeatureOverlay` is not supported any more. Instead use `ol.layer.Vector`. http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/examples/vector-layer.html this is the new version of the example. What is not wokring?